# Unlist data.frame column of individual lists and preserve each cell as a vector

Tags: r, list

First time posting so apologies if it doesn't meet standards! I'm working on a simulation in which I'm using `cut()` to create ordinal variables drawn from a multivariate normal distribution. I'm attempting to create a data.frame using `expand.grid()` containing all of my conditions and then run `mdply()` to 'sew it all together.' A particular column in that df is `df$k`, which contains vectors of cut points which will be fed into `cut()`:

```
n <- c(25,50)
p <- c(0,.1)
k <- list(c(-Inf,0,Inf), c(-Inf,-1,1,Inf))
factors <- list(n=n, p=p, k=k)
df <- expand.grid(factors) 

fx <- function(n, p, k){
    data <- mvrnorm(n,c(0,0),matrix(c(1,p,p,1),2,2))
    x <- cut(data[,1],k)
    y <- cut(data[,2],k)
    dat <- cbind(x,y)
}
```

My issue is that although my table of conditions looks correct, `df$k` is actually a list of 8 lists, and when fed into `mdply()` gives the error: `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'` (I'm assuming that's why the error is popping up.) So essentially I'd like to unlist each cell so that each cell is simply a vector `c(-Inf, 0, Inf)`. It will look exactly like df does now, but I believe it will solve the problem. `unlist(df$k)` creates one long vector, and loses the cuts I need--`unlist(df$k[[x]])`does the trick, but I need to do that to each element of the column.

Here's the code that produces the error:

```
test <- mdply(df, .fun = runSim) #runSim contains fx above and an estimation function
```

Comment: Please provide the line that gives you the error. Not clear what "fed into mdply()" means. Also, provide your desired output.

Comment: Is `Map(fx,df$n,df$p,df$k` close to what you are looking for?

Comment: No, the only change I need is to df$k, which represents different entries into the function `cut(data, breaks = k)`. `k` needs to be a vector of numeric cut points and for whatever reason, when I call df into mdply to run the full simulation, I get an error about a list object not being able to convert to a type 'integer'. My inclination is that it would be resolved if df$k was not a series of lists, but instead vectors of numeric cutpoints.

Comment: Is as.vector() of any help

Comment: Afraid not--same error.

Comment: If you don't provide a fully reproducible example it's unlikely you'll receive any useful help. Why `runSim` is not provided? Please, make an effort to at least describe your desired output and in what the `Map` line I provided above is different from what you are expecting.